# Getting a reference to System.String from System.Runtime.dll instead of from mscorlib

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, f#, windows-runtime

I have a reference to `System.Runtime.dll` that I got using `Assembly.ReflectionOnlyLoad`.
When I call `.GetType("System.String")` on it, I get the `System.String` type in `mscorlib`, instead of the one in `System.Runtime`, which will cause me problems as I'll generate the wrong IL. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried using the full name? "System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089"

Comment: What is `System.Runtime.dll`? The [source code](https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/65aefd97497e41787453cf23c8936ed2de2764c7/mcs/class/Facades/System.Runtime/TypeForwarders.cs) in mono only contains a list of type forwarders to mscorlib types.

Comment: String type inside System.Runtime? are you sure?

Comment: Yes, System.String is defined in System.Runtime.dll for WinRT applications

Comment: You have the wrong file.  It needs to be the *reference* assembly, not the one you dug out of the GAC or got from c:\windows, if you want to see System.String defined in System.Runtime.dll.  Reference assemblies live in c:\program files\reference assemblies on Windows.

Comment: If I use the reference assemblies (either C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETCore\v4.5 or C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework\.NETPortable\v4.5\Profile\Profile7) instead of the gac assemblies I get this error on the first .GetType call: `Could not load type 'System.Object' from assembly 'System.Runtime, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' because the parent does not exist.`

Answer (score 1):

What you see there is the result of assembly unification. When you're emitting assemblies using the System.Reflection APIs, there is no easy way to avoid leaking metadata (e.g. Type) references from your environment into the resulting assembly. That's because the S.R Api's were meant for runtime code generation, not for generating some output to be saved.

You may try using something like Mono.Cecil which is a lot more suited for that purpose.